# Detect the right name in string

Tags: php

So I was wondering how to detect the right files, by their names, when I scan through them.

Right now when I open a pop-up window, I `GET` a id (`?id=2451961`), and this id is used to detect `image` files in a folder. But how should i detect them?

Is there a way to say, the start of the files name to the first non-number should be the id, and if it's equal to the id then thats one of the files?

The folder with some files could be this:

[image]

Right now I loop through the files like this, but it doesn't get the file `'2451961 - Copy.png'`:

```php
foreach ($list as $file) {
    $file_name = strtolower(substr(strtok($file, '.'),0));
    $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
    if ($type != "log" ) {
        if ((strtok($file, '_') == $id) || $file_name == $id) {
            $scr = '../test/ftp_image.php?img='.$file;
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $scr; ?>" height="250px"/> <?php

            echo $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: there is a statement `exclude = .log files` in the code, which is because there is some files containing text which shouldn't be takes into consideration.

The files i want to get in this example is these:

[image]

NOTE: Not all images will be .png, there could be a .jpg or something like that.

**file names:**

```
2451961 - Copy.png
2451961.jpg
2451961 - Copy 2.png
2451961 - Copy_2.jpeg
```

Comment: How are you generating the `$list` array variable?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I get them using a `FTP server connection`, the php ftp function is this `ftp_nlist(...);`, and I just loop that list of files.

Comment: Is this a searchable questuon title for your topic/problem? I doubt people with a similar challenge will find this page by your title.  Please [edit] your title to uniquely describe your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex looks like a better/right tool for this job. Your regex could look like below:

```
'/^'.preg_quote($id).'\D/'
```

[`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) is just for escaping of any regex metacharacters. So, your file name should start with the ID followed by a non digit, which is `\D`. We won't have to care about file extensions if we do it this way.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$files = [
    '2451961 - Copy.png',
    '2451961.png',
    '2451961_2 - Copy.png',
    '2451961_2.png',
    '4405.png'
];

$id = '2451961';

foreach($files as $file){
    echo $file, " ", var_dump(preg_match('/^'.preg_quote($id).'\D/', $file) === 1),PHP_EOL;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50629967397317f629075eb98e19c845a1f5221c)

Comment: `.log` files are also suitable for this pattern, which are excluded in the question.

Comment: @7-zete-7 Yes, but the screenshots show only images as of now. If logs per every ID is  being produced, I would rather suggest the structure to be something like `folder/logs` and `folder/images` instead of mixing them up in a single folder. The lookup is also easier this way.

Comment: This will work, thanks! I just included  `$type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));` in my code too, just to exclude all `.log` files.

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup Great, but I would still suggest moving them to a separate log folder for a good design.

Comment: @nice_dev, sometimes you have to work with what you already have. Perhaps this is just such a case.

Comment: @nice_dev you're probably right, might make a log folder and a image folder on my `FTP_server`

Comment: @7-zete-7 you're right, at least I have the option to change this since we just started developing the FTP.

Comment: @nice_dev what exactly does `preg_match('/^'.preg_quote($id).'\D/', $file)` do?

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup Hope my answer helped you. `preg_match('/^'.preg_quote($id).'\D/', $file)` checks if `$file` matches the pattern `/^'.preg_quote($id).'\D/`. If it does, it returns an integer `1`, else a `0`. More info- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: and `'/^'` and `'\D/'` represent?

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup `^` means match from the beginning of the string and `\D` means match any non-digit character. The `/` is just a delimiter and isn't exactly a part of the pure regex. It is used more to provide additional features for a regex such as case-insensitive match, multiline match or unicode matching support etc. You can learn more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup So for your example, the regex would be `/^2451961\D/` meaning match with the file name if it starts from `2451961` followed by a non digit character.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are unable to use `glob` then perhaps combining `preg_grep` with `ftp_nlist` directly might be a suitable method once you have build a suitable regex

```
$id='2451961';
$pttn=sprintf('@(%1$s.+?\.png|%1$s.+?\.jpg|%1$s.+?\.jpeg|%1$s.+?\.gif)@',$id );
$col=preg_grep( $pttn, ftp_nlist( $conn, $dir ) );
print_r($col);
```

Comment: Why is `glob()` not an option? Where was that mentioned?  ...ah, a comment under a deleted answer -- I found it.

Comment: Does `glob` work on FTP shares?

Comment: Why not `@%s.+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)@`?  ...more D.R.Y.  And I don't know the limitations of `glob()` with FTP shares -- I never tried it.  I do know that `glob()` can be used to directly filter filenames and extensions.

Comment: indeed! More than one way to skin a cat as they say but I'd just expanded upon my original `preg_grep` - to be fair though that regex looks far more elegant though but the `:` ?

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.  A group for logical grouping only, not for generating subsets of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `strpos` to search needle substring. Its return you false if not found what you want and code will be like that

```
if (strpos($file, $id) !== false) {
        $scr = '../test/ftp_image.php?img='.$file;
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $scr; ?>" height="250px"/> <?php

        echo $file;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Thx Movs to correct this code

Comment: `if strpos($file, $id) !== false) {` The !== operator should be used with strpos.  Using != would not work as expected because if the position of value to search is 0 the statement is (0 != false) evaluates to false.

Comment: With this condition, a file named `123456.png` will also work if `$id` is equal to `123`, or `345`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PCRE like:

```php
$pattern = '/\b' . preg_quote($id, '/') . '(?:_\d+)?(?: - Copy)?\.(?!log)[a-z]+$/';
foreach ($list as $file) {
  if (preg_match($pattern, $file)) {
    $scr = '../test/ftp_image.php?img='.$file;
    ?><img src="<?php echo $scr; ?>" height="250px"/> <?php

    echo $file;
  }
}
```

An example of how it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/WMw6ir/2).

In pattern (for example `$id` be equal `'123'`):

- `\b` — work break. `'12345'` match, `'0123'` doesn't match
- `preg_quote($id, '/')` — escaping `$id` value from PCRE syntactic chars
- `(?:_\d+)?` — adds potential support of `123_1`, `123_34`, etc file name suffixes
- `(?: - Copy)?` — adds potential supporting of `123 - Copy` file name
- `(?:_\d+)?(?: - Copy)?` — (combination) adds potential supporting of `123_2 - Copy` file names
- `\.(?!log)[a-z]+$` — disables the `.log` file extensions while allowing all others